# I want to add an include_path but don't have access to php.ini

Tags: 7

I was thinking I could use the php function `set_include_path()` to accomplish this, but I'm not sure which file I should include this in. `template.php` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`settings.php` would probably be the safest bet.

The `template.php` file might well be included too late in the process to have the desired effect, but `settings.php` is included indirectly from [`drupal_bootstrap()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7) so should take effect before any of your custom code has a chance to run.

If you don't want to alter `settings.php` in that way you could implement [`hook_boot()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) in a custom module which is also invoked very early on in the page build process.